# Finding Time and Space Complexity Of Recursive Functions

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I am stumbling at anlayzing the time and space complexities of recursive functions:

consider:

```
def power(a, n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a*power(a, n-1)
```

When finding time complexity of this: I think `T(n) = c + T(n-1)` where c is the constant cost of the multiplication.

This will probably lead to: c*n cost, i.e. linear cost O(n). But recursions are usually exponential in cost.

Also, consider this function:

```
def power(a,n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    if n%2 ==0:
        return power(a*a, n//2)
    else:
        return a*power(a*a, n//2)
```

The above function will go on till: `T(n) = c + T(n/2)` which means the cost will be c*log(n) means log(n) complexity.

If the analysis is correct then recursion looks to be as fast as iterative algorithms, so where does the overhead come from and are there any exponential recursive algorithms?

Comment: You might to separate the Order of the function from how quickly it operates in practice (on small datasets) - a simple power function, done iteratively, has vastly smaller overhead than a recursive function, where you set up a new stack frame and branch every time through.

Recursive functions aren't necessarily exponential, as your analysis shows. Howevr they tend to be practically useful on things like tree-walks, where they bifurcate unpredictably, and in this case, they are exponential (but much easier to implement, and just as good as,non recursive functions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that recursions are exponential in complexity. In fact there is a theorem that each recursive algorithm has an iterative analogue and vice versa(possibly using additional memory). For explanation on how to do this see [here](https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/recursionConversion/page/recursionConversion.html) for instance. Also have a look at the section in wikipedia that compares [recursion and iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursion_versus_iteration).

When a recursive function calls itself more than once in some of its flows, you may end up with exponential complexity as is the famous example with fibonacci numbers:

```
def fib(n):
   if n < 2:
       return 1
   return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

But this does not mean there is no faster recursive implementation. For instance using [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) you can get that down to linear complexity.

Still recursive implementations really are a bit slower, because the stack frame should be stored when doing a recursive call and it should be restored when returning the value.

Comment: could you state the theorem or name/links to it..also how to show the above algo has exponential complexity by analysis? Thanks!!

Comment: I have added a link to a constructive proof - an example algorithm to do the conversion

Comment: @AndyMarkman as for showing why the above algorithm has exponential complexity I prefer to leave that bit to you. From your question it seems you have pretty good handle of it and both your estimates are correct

Comment: Thanks, I will try: T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) and T(n-1) = T(n-2) + T(n-3) and T(n-2) = T(n-3) + T(n-4) => there are two function calls for every value of n... and then, it looks like: there are n levels and at each level there are branches: no. of branches = function calls = 2*2 * 2 n times => 2^n. I was thinking why it is not: 2 + 2 + 2 + 2...  but for that new function calls have to be stopped...

Comment: Good start. One more thing to note is that you compute some values multiple times - for instance both T(n - 1) and T(n-2) depend on `T(n-3)`. Can you estimate how many times the function is called for each argument?

Comment: it appears it is a fibonnaci series. n is called 1 times, n-1 = 1 time, n-2 = 2, n-3 = 3, n-4 = 5.... so total number of base calls made = fibonacci(n) .. then it looks complexity is less than exponential bcz is fibonacci is slower than exponential https://www.burgundywall.com/post/fibonacci-vs-exponential-growth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165039/discussion-between-ivaylo-strandjev-and-andy-markman).